# Random vector with joint density

Tags: probability

Let $(X,Y) $ a random vector with joint density
$$ f_{(X,Y)} (x,y) =3(x+y)1_{(0,1)}(x+y)1_{(0,1)}(x) 1_{(0,1)}(y) $$
$a) $ Calculates the functions of marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ respectively
Hello, I wanted to learn a little about random variables and see a study about manifolds, since I do not have a specific book many times I download pdfs from different authors, in the questions above is a practical exercise and not theory what I'd like to know or what confuses me is notation 
$$ f_{(X,Y)} (x,y) =3(x+y)1_{(0,1)}(x+y)1_{(0,1)}(x) 1_{(0,1)}(y) $$ 
I tried to solve others, seen examples but I had not come across such a notation, I have always seen it with an explicit function in variables x, and how I could translate it to something like this.

For example, I know 
$$ f_{(X,Y)} (x,y) =xy+y^{3}$$ 
For some conditions to $x, y$

Thanks to the comments, I have understood that
$$ f_{(X,Y)} (x,y) =3(x+y)1_{(0,1)}(x+y)1_{(0,1)}(x) 1_{(0,1)}(y) $$
is equivalent to

$$ f_{(X,Y)} (x,y) =3(x+y) $$
if $0<x<1$,$0<y<1$ and $0<x+y<1$, $0$ in another case,I know that by definition the joint density must meet 2 requirements

$1)$ $0 \leq f_{(X,Y)} (x,y) $ this is inmediatly from the conditions

$2)$ $\int _{-\infty }^{\infty } \int _{-\infty }^{\infty } f_{(X,Y)} (x,y) dydx=1$ To verify this I must give adequate integration limits which are given by the conditions on $ x $ and $ y $ in this case $\int _{0 }^{1 } \int _{0 }^{1-x } 3(x+y) dydx$  I have verified that it is 1, is it correct? my procedure was

Comment: What have you tried? Which part is confusing you?

Comment: Sorry. we don't do your homework. Can you show what you have done so far and where you are stuck?

Comment: Sorry, I know this forum is not for doing tasks if I don't discuss ideas, what happened is that I sent it before I put my comment

Comment: The notation $1_A(x)$ is an indicator function. It equals $1$ if $x\in A$ and equals $0$ otherwise.

Comment: So I can multiply $f_{(X,Y)} (x,y) =3(x+y)(x+y)(x)(y) $? And then integrate as the method to find the marginals says

Comment: In your case, this means $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 3(x+y)$ if $0<x+y<1,0<x<1,0<y<1$ and $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=0$ else.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand, being a two-dimensional random variable has to be described in a region of the plane in this case could be a triangle.